# What's the difference between a vector network analyzer (VNA) and a frequency response analyzer (FRA?)?

Tags: vna

I know what a VNA does, but what does an FRA do that's different? From what I can find, an FRA seems to be primarily used in electrochemistry and other physical sciences, where what is being tested isn't an electrical component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short anwer could be: A VNA measures scattering parameters (which are dimensionless ratios of wave amplitudes) of a frequency swept input signal versus a FRA measures amplitude and phase change of a frequency swept input signal.

Both are mainly used in measuring electrical components or circuits.